# Elasticsearch: how to extract possible pattern over multiple events with same session id

Tags: elasticsearch

**Summary:**

I use elasticsearch for my weblogs. I want to get an anwser to the question: how many clients requested page A and page B within one session?

**Details:**

My Elasticsearch node contains the events that are logged on my website. Each event contains amongst others timestamp, url, referrer and session id. At this moment I know how to find e.g. how many sessions requested url xyz. But I don't know how to find if there are cases that within a session both page A and page B are requested. And of course not that page A or B is part of the referrer.
Is this something that is somehow supported within elasticsearch?

Comment: Should be possible with a `filtered` query using `bool` filters. Checkout [combining filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html). Then do [`terms`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation on `session_id`... What have you tried so far?

Comment: llernestal thanks for you comment. I tried your suggestion but this doesn't seem to have to desired effect. With this I get back all the sessions with page A (but not perse with page B) or sessions with page A and B (this is where i'm interested in) or sessions with only page B (but not perse with page A).

Answer (score 0):

The query should look something like this (assuming your `url` and `session_id` are `not_analyzed`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "url": "[Page A URL]"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "url": "[Page B URL]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "requested_both_pages": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "session_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `doc_count` in the response will be the number you're looking for.

Keep in mind that if your url is analyzed and you need to do fuzzy matching then you'll have to use a `match` query instead of the `terms` filter. I generally wouldn't recommend an analyzed referrer. Instead I would break it down into its parts and create a nested url object with each string `not_analyzed` and then use a `terms` filter. You can do a [wildcard query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) with `not_analyzed` fields still if you need some fuzziness.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your comment. The query doesn't seem to work, but I guess that's beceause the second term has to be within new brackets. But the principle of this query is also not working for me as it will never give me any result. I think this query search for events that has both url = page A and url = page B within the same event. But it has to be over all events that share the same session_id.

Comment: I fixed the typo in that answer; however, you are correct, this is a much tougher problem. I think there might be a way with some sub aggregations and maybe a [filter aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) but I'll have to give it some more thought.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a query that at least returns how many times url A and url B are requested per session. I was not aware that I could use this style of aggregation. Still not the perfect solution as it can return sessions where url A has counts and url B has no counts. So I will not mark the anwser as solved. Unless some expert can tell me that my request is just not possible at all.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "Url": "[Page A URL]"
              }
            },
            {  
              "term": {
                "Url": "[Page B URL]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sessions_all": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "session_id",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Page_A_URL": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Url": "[Page A URL]"
            }
          }
        },
        "Page_B_URL": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Url": "[Page A URL]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```